# The phrase: "It was the better part of our conversation": does it mean qualitative or time spent?

Tags: colloquialisms

I've always intuitively assumed that the phrase "better part of our conversation" would mean the topic on which more time was spent.

This is in contrast to ranking and grading the other aspects of the conversation.  E.g.

> "After he said I love you, he spent the better part of the conversation talking about household maintenance, chores etc"

Obviously they aren't saying chores are more important that "I love you".  So is my usage of this phrase inconsistent with the meaning of better?

Comment: Generally "better" just means "superior," but in the phrase "the better part of," it almost definitely means "longer" or "bigger."

Comment: General reference - see [idiom definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+better+part+of)
 and [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/better).  Your usage is fine.

Answer (score 2):

*Better* can certainly be used in the sense of [*larger* or *greater*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18370?rskey=2MaLTL&result=2#eid). In my experience it tends to be used most often in this sense when referring to a length of time or a distance:

> We walked for the better part of five hours before reaching the
>   waterfall.

The phrase *the best part* can also be used in this context.